# Create multiple colour progress bar

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I want to create progress bar with multiple colours, it can be in 5 fix colours (as setProgress(100/20 ratio)).

How we can divide progress bar in fix part's with colour ?

can some one please suggest me is there any library or example for this ?.

also I want to display text in center of the progress bar.

Here is the Progress bar view, thanks in advance for any help and suggestions..:)

[image: Progress bar view]

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class has a function drawArc, which does what you need.

This code gives you sort of a hint.

```
   private static final int ARCS_COUNT = 4;
   private static final int SWEEP_ANGLE = 360/(ARCS_COUNT+1);   // 72
   private static final int[] colours = 
            new int[] {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};


   .....

   Paint p = new Paint();
   p.SetStyle(PaintStyle.STROKE);
   p.setStrokeWidth(4):

   // Point (50,50) will be the centre of the bar.
   RectF rectF = new RectF(0,0,100,100); 
   int startAngle = 180;

   for (int i = 0; i<ARCS_COUNT; i++) {
     p.setColor(colours[i]);
     canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, SWEEP_ANGLE, false, p);
     startAngle += SWEEP_ANGLE;     
   }
```